# ElasticSearch JDBC river Java api

Tags: elasticsearch, java, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

My goal is to index MySQL database to ElasticSearch.

There are no.of tutorials are available about indexing sql database to ElasticSearch through command line. But i need to perform the same through java code ie, using an api.

Can anyone provide a tutorial to ElasticSearch JDBC river java api?

Comment: there is not api for the elasticsearch-jdbc-river. It's an elasticsearch-plugin!

Comment: yeah i know that, I meant, I need an equivalent java code of the command line. Means I need to programmatically connect to a sql database and index data to ElasticSearch using the JDBC plugin.

Comment: that means : JDBC api + Elasticsearch api or a better solution might be the use of [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch.git)